# APSW (or SQLite3) very slow INSERT on executemany

Tags: python, sqlite, apsw

I have found the following issue with APSW (an SQLite parser for Python) when inserting lines.

Lets say my data is `data = [[1,2],[3,4]]`

APSW and SQLite3 allow me to do something like:

```
apsw.executemany("INSERT INTO Table VALUES(?,?)", b)
```

or I can write some code that does the following:

```
sql = "BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
INSERT INTO Table Values('1','2');
INERT INTO Table Values('3','4');
COMMINT;"

apsw.execute(sql)
```

When `data` is a long list/array/table the performance of the first method is extremelly slow compared to the second one (for 400 rows it can be 20 sec vs less than 1!). I do not understand why this is as that is the method shown on all SQLite Python tutorials to add data into a table.

Any idea of what may be happening here?

Comment: Transactions are quicker than just executing sql. You can do the same thing with first method by adding `aspw.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION")` before you `executemany` and `aspw.execute("COMMIT")` when you're done

Comment: @Confuseh Actually, many transactions [are slower](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19).

Comment: @CL. Many transactions are slower, indeed, but one transaction and a lot of inserts in transaction is still quicker than inserts without transaction.

Comment: Confuseh CL thank you both for the replies and interesting links. Hope this thread may help people with similar problems in the future

Comment: @Confuseh It is not possible to have inserts without transactions; without explicit `BEGIN`/`COMMIT`, you get one [automatic transaction](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) for each statement.

Comment: @CL. I phrased it wrong, but that's what I meant. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 9):

(Disclosure: I am the author of APSW).  If you do not explicitly have a transaction in effect, then SQLite automatically starts one at the beginning of each statement, and ends at the end of each statement.  A write transaction is durable - meaning the contents must end up on storage and fsync called to ensure they will survive an unexpected power or system failure.  Storage is slow!

I recommend using `with` rather than BEGIN/COMMIT in your case, because it will automatically rollback on error.  That makes sure your data insertion either completely happens or not at all.  See [the documentation](https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/connection.html#apsw.Connection.__enter__) for an example.

When you are inserting a lot of data, you will find [WAL mode](https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/tips.html#write-ahead-logging) to be more performant.

Comment: Hello Roger, thanks so much for your detailed explanation! It is not everyday one has the developer behind the tool you use every day write on your StackOverflow post!!!!!

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to Confuseh I got the following answer:

Executing:

```
apsw.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION;")
apsw.executemany("INERT INTO Table VALUES(?,?)", b)
apsw.execute("COMMIT;")
```

Speeds up the process by A LOT! This seems to be the right way of adding data (vs using my method of creating multiple INSERT statments).

Comment: THANK YOU damn my process went litteraly from 10min to 5 seconds with this.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this question, the answer help me when I use Sqlite with Python. finally, I get the following things, and wish it can help some people :

When connct to the sqlite database we can use

`con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:",isolation_level=None)` or `con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")`

---

when use isolation_level=None, it will use autocommit mode that make too many transaction , and become too slow. this will help:

```
cur.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION")
cur.executemany(....)
cur.execute("COMMIT")
```

And if use `con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")`, `cur.executemany(....)` will be fast immediately.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

There may be a confusion for `mysqlclient-python`/`pymysql` users who expect `executemany` of `sqlite3`/`apsw` to rewrite their `INERT INTO table VALUES(?, ?)` into a multi-row `INSERT` statement.

For instance, [`executemany`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/ca630c01/MySQLdb/cursors.py#L209) of `mysqlclient-python` has this in its docstring:

> This method improves performance on multiple-row INSERT and REPLACE. Otherwise it is equivalent to looping over args with execute().

Python stdlib's `sqlite3.Cursor.executemany` doesn't have this optimisation. It's always loop-equivalet. Here's how to demonstrate it (unless you want to read some C, [`_pysqlite_query_execute`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b40e4343/Modules/_sqlite/cursor.c#L369)):

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', isolation_level=None)
conn.set_trace_callback(print)
conn.execute('CREATE TABLE tbl (x INTEGER, y INTEGER)')

conn.executemany('INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(?, ?)', [(i, i ** 2) for i in range(5)])
```

It prints:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (x INTEGER, y INTEGER)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(0, 0)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(1, 1)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(2, 4)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(3, 9)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(4, 16)
```

### Solution

Thus, you either need to rewrite these `INSERT`s into multi-row one (manually or, for instance, with [`python-sql`](https://pypi.org/project/python-sql/)) to stay in auto-commit mode (`isolation_level=None`), or wrap your `INSERT`s in a transaction (with sensible number of `INSERT`s in one) in default implicit-commit mode. The latter means the following for the above snippet:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.set_trace_callback(print)
conn.execute('CREATE TABLE tbl (x INTEGER, y INTEGER)')

with conn:
    conn.executemany('INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(?, ?)', [(i, i ** 2) for i in range(5)])
```

Now it prints:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (x INTEGER, y INTEGER)
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(0, 0)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(1, 1)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(2, 4)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(3, 9)
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(4, 16)
COMMIT
```

For further bulk-insert performance improvement in SQLite, I'd suggest to start with [this overview question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52142645/2072035).