# How to commit DB changes in a Flask or Bottle app efficiently?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I've noticed that SQLite `db.commit()` (save to disk) takes between 50ms and 100ms with my small database. This is normal and [documented here](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19), but **it's too much to do it after each request of a client / after each INSERT** like this:

```
import bottle, sqlite3, random

@bottle.route('/')
def index():
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?)', (random.randint(0, 10000)))
    c.close()
    db.commit()    # should we do it here? (100ms is too much after *each* request!)
    return 'hello'

def worker():      
    db.commit()    # or here? how to call this worker once every 10 seconds? 

db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (a int)")
bottle.run(port=80)
```

More precisely I don't want to lose 100ms after each request: I optimized my server to serve pages very fast (10ms), and it would be a shame to lose 100ms because of DB commit.

Of course I *could* start a new thread to call `worker()` only once every 10 seconds (in the worst case, if the app crashes, only the 10 last seconds of DB will be lost). But I read it's not recommended to use [threads in this context](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6).

**Question: how to do a SQLite DB commit once every few seconds only (instead of once after each INSERT) in a Bottle/Flask webserver context?**

Comment: `I don't want to lose 100ms after each request` - Why not? Very few domains are really that latency sensitive - especially on write. Is your webapp one of those exceedingly rare cases? (High frequency trading, real-time bidding, etc.)

Comment: @ronrothman I'm in a situation in which many clients might connect exactly at the same time (for a precise event), I know it's usually not the case, usually the users are spread along 24 hours per day, but here they come for a specific event, with a precise starting time.

Comment: Then (if I understand you correctly) you need high throughput, not low latency. You should be thinking about increasing concurrency, not reducing latency.

Comment: @ronrothman Both would be great: not losing 100ms on each request for a commit to disk (whereas the (complex!) page is generated in less than 20ms or 30ms), and also increase concurrency. Multiplying the time for each request by a factor x6 just to log something is something we don't want, I so wanted to analyze how to avoid this. (Wouldn't be a sad that the page generation is done in a few milliseconds, and that just the small DB logging commit takes 6 times more?)

Comment: I guess some things have to be learned the hard way. :) I highly recommend that you stop worrying about the 100ms. Good luck!

Comment: @ronrothman I did not say I won't increase concurrency. I will do it. But I'm also trying to understand if having a small DB logging eating 6x more time than the actual page generation/serving can be avoided. I think it's sane to study this, don't you think so?

Comment: IMO the only reasons you should be spending time on the 100ms are (1) you have a `requirement` of very low latency, or (2) you're having fun working on optimizing your webapp. Other than that, no.

Comment: @ronrothman Sure for (2), I admit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a Flask [after_request()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.after_request) handler and commit the database there. You may even restrict to do this only if a certain amount of time has elapsed since the last commit.

This won't block your requests and will not save the file too often.

Comment: Interesting method, but it has a few drawbacks. Example: request #100 (DB commit), request #101 (no DB commit because DB commit has already been done 1 second before), then wait 30 seconds, and server is stopped (`app.py` is killed or stopped with CTRL+C). Then the INSERT of request #101 is ... lost! Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

Here is an attempt. It only commits once every 10 second, if there is an INSERT during this timeframe.

NB: it requires `check_same_thread=False`, as explained in [ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218065/programmingerror-sqlite-objects-created-in-a-thread-can-only-be-used-in-that-sa).

```
import bottle, sqlite3, random, threading, time

@bottle.route('/')
def index():
    global committhread
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?)', (random.randint(0, 10000),))
    c.close()
    if not committhread: 
        print('Calling commit()...')
        committhread = threading.Thread(target=commit)
        committhread.start()
    else:
        print('A commit is already planned.')
    return 'hello'

def commit():
    global committhread
    print("We'll commit in 10 seconds.")
    time.sleep(10)  # I hope this doesn't block/waste CPU here?
    db.commit()
    print('Committed.')
    committhread = None    

db = sqlite3.connect('test.db', check_same_thread=False)
db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (a int)")
committhread = None
bottle.run(port=80)
```

---

But as discussed in [SQLite and Python: commit once every 10 seconds maximum, and not after every client request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/241753/sqlite-and-python-commit-once-every-10-seconds-maximum-and-not-after-every-cli) there are some other options worth trying before doing the previous code, such as:

```
c.execute('PRAGMA synchronous = OFF')
c.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF')
```

This improves performance by at least an order of magnitude.

Useful resources:

- https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html
- https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous
- [How to improve SQLite insert performance in Python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52142645/how-to-improve-sqlite-insert-performance-in-python-3-6)

Comment: I totally accept the downvote (downvotes are useful when an answer is bad); if the downvoter could leave a comment about what is wrong, it would be super useful/heplful, and it would help me. Thanks in advance!